# Requisites in data in order to use Gaussian Mixture Models

Tags: gaussian-mixture-distribution

I would like to know if I want to use GMM if the data has to follow a Gaussian distribution even if I preprocess the data and normalize it. Is it enough to normalize the data or has it have to pass some type of test?

Regards and thank you in advance